# Using ViewPager with native Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library

Can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I'm creating an Android app which uses Fragments. So far I've been using the native ones as opposed to the support library ones because I'm aiming the app at the Nexus 7. However I've no problem using the support library if it makes no difference to development (I read something about no ActionBar?).

My problem is that I want to have a fragment that fills half the screen and shows a swipeable tabs type area. I want the user to be able to swipe left and right and be shown different Fragments for each "page" (Nested Fragments I know but I read that they're supported now). Basically I want it to be like the Play Store when you're swiping between Top Paid, Top Free etc. except only take up half the screen (which I achieve using a Fragment), the other half of the screen is another Fragment I have already written. Another thing is that within each "page" (such as Top Free etc.) I want to have 2 ListViews.

[image: Crude drawing of what I'm trying to achieve]

However it seems that the ViewPager component is only part of the support libraries which I think means I have to change all of my fragments to the support ones. Is this the only way to achieve this layout? There must be an easier way; I've seen something called the Workspace on a Google I/O video before so I assumed it's a very common UI design pattern.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can use native fragments with a viewpager, although I'm using support fragments for my app. It's really easy to change them to support fragments.

Comment: Yeah last I tried to use native fragments with a viewpager I ended up converting to support fragments due frustration :)

Comment: You can't, not unless you get the sourcecode for ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter and modify them. ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter exist only in the SupportLibrary and it needs an instance of the Support Fragment Manager in order to use Fragments.

Comment: Plus one for making your own drawing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You want the ViewPager, and switching your fragments to support library ones is a very easy conversion.

And you'll probably want this for more customization :)
http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Ok I converted everything over fine but as I feared the ActionBar is causing issues. Is there an easy way around this? I'm reading the Android documentation and it says something about being able to add actions to the menu bar anyway but I need the tab functionality that's built into the ActionBar. It's vital to my project.

Comment: Sorry I figured it out. I just left the tab code as-is but in the methods which required an android.app.FragmentTransaction (as part of the TabListener interface) I simply ignored the passed transaction and used my own instance of a transaction from the support library. Worked perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: Hey. Sorry I wasn't on to help out. I'm glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 5):

You can use ViewPager with native fragments, there are adapters for it in the [android.support.v13.app](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/package-summary.html) package. You need the v13 support jar to be able to use them.

But there might be advantages with using support fragments anyway: [Fragment or Support Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment)