# Fragment or Support Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an app that supports Android >= 4.0. It uses fragments from the `android.app` package. As I am facing problems with the older fragment implementation in 4.0, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540712/app-crashes-on-super-onsaveinstancestate), that are already fixed in the support library, I am considering switching back to the fragment implementation from the support library to get a more reliable and consistent implementation.

What is your opinion on this? Are you using fragments from the support library, even though they are already available, when developing for Android 4?

Comment: This is a nice question (+1 because it make me curious). Also there isn't a good explanation on the web for this. I'm using support library for my app and i wonder if i'm wrong or not, because i didn't notice any error while compiling or during test.

Comment: @animuson The answer by brillenheini proves that this is not a primarily opinion based answer.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

From my experience, using the same fragment implementation on all Android devices is a great advantage. I could not get rid of all NullPointerExceptions when state is saved on Android 4.0 using native fragments, with the support library they are all gone. Also I could not see any disadvantage so far with this approach.

So my answer to my own question is now: When developing for Android 4.x, using the fragments from the support library is a good idea. The support library has bugs fixed that are still present in older fragment implementations and is frequently updated with more bug fixes.

Comment: So what's the purpose of the `android.app.Fragment` then? If you can add this to your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager/) with a bit more explanation, I would be fully satisfied.  Thanks!

Comment: @jonstaff The reason is probably historic. Please see my updated answer there.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there seem to be things support fragments cannot do (e.g. [being animated with `objectAnimator`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16734364/11683), even if the actual target OS supports it). Which, in case you are using `ViewPager`, means that you have to use adapters from v13 support library, otherwise you can't have both viewpager and flipping animation.

Comment: Also be careful, as of August 2014, the v13 library can't do Nested Fragments.

Comment: Why does the guys at google opted for using the v13 library for iosched app https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/MyScheduleActivity.java , they must have some reason

Comment: Is this still valid with android 6.x coming out?

Comment: Nice to hear the experiences, this adds lot of value to others' work. All nice answers.

Answer (score 40):

One big reason to stick with the `SupportFragment` for a while is that you do not have access to the `ChildFragmentManager` until API 17.  The support library will give you a support version of the child fragment manager.

This becomes a big deal if you have fragments that contain other fragments.  This is common in  tablet applications with a good deal of complexity and/or your overall architecture is based on either a tabbed layout or uses the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 21):

I was also getting frustrated at having to include the support libraries, despite targeting Android 4.0+ - but it seems it is officially recommended:

> The Android Support Library package contains several libraries that
>   can be included in your application. Each of these libraries supports
>   a specific range of Android platform versions and set of features.
>
> This guide explains the important features and version support
>   provided by the Support Libraries to help you decide which of them you
>   should include in your application. **In general, we recommend including
>   the v4 support and v7 appcompat libraries, because they support a wide
>   range of Android versions and provide APIs for recommended user
>   interface patterns.**

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, despite the fact that @brillenheini provided an answer himself/herself. It answers the question with the best accuracy and conciseness.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO if you are planning to develop for 4.0 only, I would recommend going with the native libraries since the executable will get smaller. It is true that you might run into problems of bugs in early versions, but I think most of these should be fairly trivial to work around. Also the compatibility library is supposed to map to the native fragments in case you are running on 4.0 and higher anyway. So you might end up having to struggle with these kinds of problems anyway.
The problem with the support libraries is that you have a lot of the classes appear 2x (once in the support package structure and once in the "native" package structure) which makes development a bit more cumbersome.

However, if you want to also release your app pre 4.0 then there is no way around the support library. Also since there are about 38% of all users on 2.3 it might make business sense to include this OS version. In such a case you can use the support library in combination with Jake Wartons ActionBarSherlock (or with googles support ActionBar Library once it is finally released).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I need ViewPager, I have to include the support library anyway. Also, the support fragment does not try to switch to the native implementation if available. That's what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) say.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is (as @brillenheini said) that to have the ViewPager you need v4, so even if you are targeting only v13+ devices you'll likely finish having the v4 anyway.

Comment: I just discovered that too (ViewPager needs v4) on my API 21 and on app. Meh :-/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is better to use Support Library now because I saw the statement here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

> This class was deprecated in API level P. Use the Support Library
>   Fragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to
>   Lifecycle.