# Fragments not working correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have came across a very strange problem, i am using Pager in android to navigate between different screens through fragments in android. also i am using another fragment class to create Layouts automatically in a grid,

for fragment 1, where i have used the pager and pageradapter i am using these imports

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

for the other fragment which i am using to populate images in a non linear Grid, i am using this import

```
import android.app.Fragment;

The issue is:
```

By using this import i am unable to add my fragments into the pageradapter. it keeps on giving me error.

```
 private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
            List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

            fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Tv Shows"));
            fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Movies"));
            fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Music Videos"));

            return fList;
        }
```

also i cannot initialize my pageadapter

```
pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

it gives me error on this line to.

```
My Question is:
```

what is difference between the two imports

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

is there any solution to the problem, ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 `import android.app.Fragment`
```

requires minimum API level your app requires is 11 or higher. to use in in application with API less than 11 you need to use support library. when using support library you should use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: what is the link between pageradapter and import android.app.Fragment`  as it does not work with this one, but it works fine with import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: because the parameter of android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter  pageradapter is android.support.v4.app.Fragment and not android.app.Fragment

refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager