# ViewPager only supported in support library?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My app needed to show many items so I implemented horizontal slides using viewpager. It works ok but I noticed my app size jumped up to about 3.5M. That's almost 3M increase by adding v13.compat library I guess. Can I do slides without support library?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager

Comment: "That's almost 3M increase by adding v13.compat library I guess" -- try a release build, one that has ProGuard run upon it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, never used ProGuard before, with/without Proguard, apk size becomes 897K/1.2M. That's not bad. Thanks.