# Use fragments for landscape view and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library

I need to develop fragments layouts for both portrait and landscape. In landscape mode, both fragments should be displayed and in portrait mode, only first fragment should be displayed and when the user swaps the screen, then the second fragment is displayed. Similar to [these screens](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/fragment-in-android-tutorial-with-example-using-webview.html). But I don't have any ListView as the given tutorial. I am using `Android.app Fragments` so I cannot use `OnItemSelectedListener` to swap to the second fragment when in the portrait screen.

I know there is no `ViewPager` in `android.app`. So I'm confused and my question is, do I have to use both `android.support.v4.app` library (to swap fragments)and  `Android.app` Fragments(to display both fragments in landscape mode) in this scenario or else is there any other way to accomplish this?

NOTE: I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager) but I could not get an answer for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might have confused I guess. The `android.support.v4.app` is an support library to use the ViewPager from Android version `GingerBread` and above, whereas the other one is to support from `HoneyComb` and above ([see the Android version release hierarchy table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)). It is enough to use anyone, as per your requirement. If you want to support the older devices then go for v4 or else the normal one is enough.

And basically the ViewPager will swipe either direction. Even if you don't have a listview, you can swipe right to the next screen.

Check [this simple ViewPager tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

**Update:**

As you don't need swiping in the Landscape mode better to go with the `android.support.v4.app` with static fragments where you'll get the backward compatibility as well for the older devices

Comment: Thank you for the support Sha. I know to use ViewPager using android.support.v4.app. But my problem is I have to arrange fragment in landscape mode. Do have any idea to do it using android.support.v4.app or to make fragments swap using android.app? Or else I want to know do I have to use both.

Comment: Better go with v4 and in the landscape mode use the static fragments. In landscape mode you don't want any swipings rite? @ZuseeWeekin

Comment: you can mark this as answer if it suits you. so that I'll get encouraged@ZuseeWeekin

Comment: I already up vote your answer. But still I'm not clear how to implement  portrait view with two fragments using android.support.v4.app.If it is possible could you please direct me to such a example or tutorial?

Comment: pls go check this video tutorial this would help you a lot http://bit.ly/1hS9hQl @ZuseeWeekin