# Why is ViewPager in android only available in the V4 Support library

Tags: android

I must be confused, I thought the V4 support library is supposed to help older devices to have newer API's, how come there is not equivalent ViewPager class if I do not use the V4 Support library?

Comment: I think it answers it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager

Answer (score 1):

The support library is not exclusively for compatibility with newer APIs. Some of the [features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) (e.g. `ViewPager`, `DrawerLayout`, `LocalBroadcastManager`) are only present there.

As for "why", it's hard to say... I guess they wanted to make those widgets available independently of an Android release.

Comment: Thats crazy, they are hiding a feature inside a compatibility package.  And when people wants that feature they have to include that package.