# Must I use the v4 Support Library for minimum SDK 14 to get ViewPager-like operation?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need something like the `ViewPager` class.  Must I use the V4 support library or is there an alternative non-support library equivalent to ViewPager?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources ("an alternative non-support library equivalent to ViewPager") is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You are better served using this site to explain what problems you have with using `support-v4` or `support-v13`, and perhaps we can help you address those problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android.app Fragments vs. android.support.v4.app using ViewPager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager)