# Is it possible to use android.app.Fragment with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-android

How would I use **android.app.Fragment;** inside **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

It only supports returning: **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**.  An existing fragment I am using inherits from RxFragment which doesn't use the support library fragment.

Comment: I ended up using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553374/android-app-fragments-vs-android-support-v4-app-using-viewpager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` are part of the support library, and only support the support Fragments.

If you really want to do this, you could copy the source for those classes and replace the support Fragment imports with framework Fragment imports.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `android.app.Fragment` if you use [`android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) from the v13 Support Library. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17556988/1843329) answer from @brillenheini