# Add library in android Studio

Tags: android

Its very hard to describe my problem but I'll do my best  <<

when I want to make a ViewPager in MainActivity , I go to xml then :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    />
```

then I make an Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

here , I need to import

```
android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

the QUESTION is ;

is there any problem when I use v4 , v13 on one application

note : I add the v13 library and make it as (provided)

Comment: why would you use it ?

Comment: you can use android support design library. It's very usefu and easy to implement.

Comment: Answer to your question: Granted you meet the minimum SDK requirement for both (i.e. minSDK="16" for example), there should be no problem with  using both in the same application (most people end up using 4 and 7). However, `FragmentPagerAdapter` also exists in support v4: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html so you shouldn't need to import v13 just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand you can use both v4 and v13 support **packages**. Sometimes you have to.

For example [`android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [`android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) are similar but not identical : they don't use the same kind of fragments (native `android.app.Fragment` vs support `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`).

So if you want to use a `ViewPager` with native fragment you have to extend the v13 `FragmentPagerAdapter` and set it on the `ViewPager` (v4, there is only one). Of course this will only work on v13+ devices.

On the other hand you don't have to declare both **library** : the v13 support lib includes the v4, adding something like

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1"
```

in your `build.gradle` gives you access to both v4 an v13 support classes.

By the way, see [Fragment or Support Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment) for more details about native vs support fragments.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** There shouldn't be a problem using both, just don't set it as provided. Use compile as the classes are not provided by the system.

Comment: and how do you explain that there is no ViewPager in v13 but there in the Adapter for it?

Comment: Okay, I take back what I said :) I misread the documentation.

Comment: can u see my pervious question  , please , it will explain alot 
Really this bug blow up my mind !!
I see a  lecture  video  for a teacher and he use multiple libraries !!!

Comment: I made an edit, maybe that will also fix the problem from your previous question.

Comment: bro >>>> i have a new bug 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Is there any other error or warning output above the exception?

Comment: Maybe try clean the project and build it again.