# AsyncTaskLoader in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader, asynctaskloader

I have a simple fragment, trying to implement AsyncTaskLoader in it. But i am getting one compile time error :

error: incompatible types
required: 
Loader< List< String>>
found:
LoaderDrone

the error is in the onCreateLoader method. what am i missing ?

After some research i am unable to find the solution.

here is the code

```
 public class SubPlaceFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>> {


 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).startLoading();
    }


  @Override
        public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new LoaderDrone(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>> loader, List<String> data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<String>> loader) {

        }

        public static class LoaderDrone extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>> {

            public LoaderDrone(Context context) {
                super(context);
                onForceLoad();
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> loadInBackground() {
                List<String> results = null;


                return results;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are importing the correct `Loader` class.

If you're using a support Fragment (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`), you need to use a support Loader (`android.support.v4.content.Loader`).

If you're using native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`), then you need to use the native Loaders (`android.content.Loader`).

Comment: thanks mate @chessdork
whats the difference b/w native & support fragments ?

Comment: The support library backports functionality to older versions of android.  For example, Fragments were introduced in API 11, but a support fragment can be used in API 7.  Here's some more discussion on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment.