# Exclude android fragment support from my application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an application to SDK version 16 and above, As I understood the fragment framework is included in the OS framework in those versions.

I want to remove the support library fragment framework (now that the v4 support library is split) but all the other support libraries are using it (com.android.support:design:25.1.0 and more).

So what is the advantage of splitting the v4 support library?

Comment: `android.app.Fragment` is included even without the support library. So, if you don't want `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, then don't compile it. Remove all the support libraries.

Comment: Well I want the Material Design support library and it uses the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: And `AppCompatActivity` extends from that, so why exactly do you want to remove it?

Comment: @cricket_007 as I wrote the fragment framework already included in the OS since Android 3.0 so it is redundant.

Comment: But if you are using Material Design, then you need an AppCompatActivity, which is a FragmentActivity, which more-or-less **should** use the support Fragments, which should be mostly compatible with the existing code. Just need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead, for example

Comment: Exactly. This why I have asked.. The Material Design should use the native fragment framework when defining minSdkVersion 11 and above.

Comment: Because there are still devices in the world running Android < 3.0 that could still use Material Design / Fragments? And I think the question you are asking is related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With respect to that particular library (`com.android.support:design`), they have not updated it to use the more-granular dependencies. With luck, they will do that someday.

In general, the advantage is to allow for flexibility. Not all apps use `com.android.support:design`, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, or other libraries that Google has not yet updated to use the more-granular dependencies. Apps that avoid those libraries can use individual dependencies (e.g., `com.android.support:compat`).

Also, you can use Gradle exclusion rules to attempt to block portions of the aggregate `support-v4` that you feel that you are not going to use. For example, you could exclude `support-fragment`, then see if your app holds up under testing (though that will not work in your specific case, since the Design Support library requires `appcompat-v7`, which in turn requires `FragmentActivity`).

Comment: I have tried to exclude the support-v4 library but it ain't compile since the design library depends on `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: @Ovi: You cannot use the Design Support library without using `appcompat-v7` and `AppCompatActivity`. That, in turn, extends `FragmentActivity`, and so you will not be able to block `support-fragment`. I updated my answer to match.